# How to sum an array of integer strings?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, integer

Question: Transform array string element to integer to sum.
My code:

```
ch = ["+7", "-3", "+10", "0"]

ch.to_i
soma = 0
string.each do |ch| 
    if ch.isdigit() 
        soma += ch.to_i
    end
end
p(soma)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
main.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `to_i' for ["+7", "-3", "+10", "0"]:Array (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  to_s
               to_a
               to_h
```

Comment: The error is happening on the second line of your code: `ch.to_i`. You are tying to convert an array to an integer, which is not a valid operation. There is also no such thing as an `ch.isdigit()` method in ruby, unless you defined it yourself!

Comment: The error is telling you that class `Array` doesn't have a `to_i` method.  You need to apply `to_i` to individual elements of the array, using `map` or iterating through the array explicitly (which would be slower).

Comment: Great! I hadn't noticed this detail. Thank you very much!

Comment: `string` is undefined, there’s no `isdigit` method. I’m not sure how that code made it to `to_i`.

Comment: What is your question? Your question starts with "Question:" and then contains two statements and no question.

Comment: This looks to be an extremely complex solution for something that is literally just `ch.sum(&:to_i)`.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of calling `to_i` on the array of strings in this line `ch.to_i` you need to call `to_i` on each element in the array like this:

```
numbers = ["+7", "-3", "+10", "0"]
sum = 0
numbers.each do |element| 
  sum += element.to_i
end
puts sum
#=> 14
```

Or simplified and using common Ruby idioms:

```
numbers = ["+7", "-3", "+10", "0"]
numbers.map(&:to_i).sum
#=> 14
```

Comment: Or `numbers.sum(&:to_i)`

Answer (score 0):

sum =0
l=list(input("enter the list you want to add"))
for i in l:
if i.isdigit():
sum=sum+i
else:
continue
print("sum of given integer strings"+sum)

Comment: This doesn't look like valid Ruby code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).